# Linux overrides /etc/hosts on windows-linux-subsystem

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had problems with hostnames resolving in windows Linux-subsystem so I removed /etc/hosts and wrote new version of it. That solution solved my problem, but after every reboot system started overriding /etc/hosts by a some default version, so I need setup hosts again and again. 
Is it possible to setup linux subsystem so it copies original windows hosts file or at least doesn't delete already written file ?

Answer (score 19):

```bsh
sudo vim /etc/wsl.conf
```

Add the following two lines:

```bsh
[network]
generateHosts = False
```

Reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/

Comment: This method works as does editing %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts - so if you want to go manual on linux or have windows update from its setting, both work.

Answer (score 8):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS as a Linux subsystem under Windows. My /etc/hosts file under Ubuntu says

```
#This file is automatically generated by WSL based on the Windows hosts file:
#%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Modifications to this file will be overwritten.
```

So I simply changed the `#%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` instead.

Comment: Editing %WINDIR%\...\hosts also works on Ubuntu 20 even though it doesn't provide the Ubuntu 16 more helpful message.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is adressed here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/398

To prevent WSL from automatically generating the /etc/hosts file on every bash startup, you need to remove the following comment line in /etc/hosts:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To prevent automatic generation of this file, remove this line.
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not have the line saying: `To prevent automatic generation of this file, remove this line.`in my /etc/hosts.

What I ended up doing was creating an addHosts.sh script with the following content:

```
MYHOSTS="ip1\thostname1\nip2\thostname2"
grep hostname1 /etc/hosts >> /dev/null || echo $MYHOSTS | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts >> /dev/null
```

The grep prevents adding the entries multiple times if you open separate instances of your linux distro.

Afterwards you have to add `sudo addHosts.sh` to your bashrc and (optionally) create an exception for sudo password prompt for this script in /etc/sudoers:

`user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/addHosts.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do `chattr +i`  on the file because the file kept getting overwritten even after I followed the instructions to add those two lines to `/etc/wsl.conf`.

NOTE - remember that you ll need `chattr -i` to be able to edit the file from anywhere again.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following zsh function based off of @R6D1H2's answer.

```
function addHosts() {
    declare -A MYHOSTS
    MYHOSTS=( 
        [host-1]="ip.add.re.ss"
        [host-2]="ip.add.re.ss"
        [host-3]="ip.add.re.ss"
        )

    for key value in ${(kv)MYHOSTS}; do
        grep $key /etc/hosts >> /dev/null || echo "$value $key" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts >> /dev/null
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/hosts file is written from your own windows hosts file.  So making changes in Windows c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file will transfer to the WSL Ubunto system.

Answer (score -2):

WSL autogenerates hosts file on each startup based on hosts file on host Windows - `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. The autogeneration may be stopped via editing `/etc/wsl.conf` like in the answers above, but a better choice in some cases is to edit the file on Windows host (administrator required).

Comment: This solution was already suggested in 2020.

Comment: Most upvoted answer shos how to stop autogeneration instead of solving problem stated in question. None of the anwers above combined or confirmed all the options.