# (WSL) How avoid overwriting Windows hosts file

Tags: windows, hosts, wsl2, overwrite, ubuntu-22.04

Bonjour,

I looked from the web et got lots of solutions but none of them work.

On Windows 11, I use Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL 2). I moved it on another drive. I also use Docker desktop and Devilbox (I can't use xdebug with VSC for the moment but is another question).

My problem is when WSL restart (or probably after a time too), the Windows hosts file is overwrite.

The solution I have found is to add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:

```
[network]
generateHosts = false
generateResolvConf = false
```

I tried with and without generateResolvConf. But it doesn't work. How I can keep the windows hosts file ?

Comment: After you modified `/etc/wsl.conf` you shutdown WSL and restarted it?  I also presume you removed the comment from the line This file was automatically generated by WSL..."[?](https://superuser.com/questions/1150597/linux-overrides-etc-hosts-on-windows-linux-subsystem)

Comment: You seem to be saying that the *Windows* host file is overwritten.  So `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`?  Or do you mean the host file *in* WSL (`/etc/hosts`)?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I restarted but didn't remove the comment in /etc/hosts.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I mean c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts. I modify this file. Should I modify the file in Ubuntu? I don't think so.

Comment: @Sinedolo Ok, that seems odd.  So you (a) make a change to the file, then (b) `wsl --shutdown`, then (c) you check the file and the changes are still there.  (d) You restart WSL and (e) check the file again and the changes are gone?

Comment: @Sinedolo - You need to remove the comment and then **shutdown** and then **restart** WSL.

Comment: @Ramhound @NotTheDr01ds Thanks both of you. I didn't remove the comment in /etc/hosts. Now yes. I added `generateHosts` and `generateResolvConf` both on false in /etc/wsl.conf as I wrote it in the question. `generateHosts` alone didn't work but with the both parametres, it seems working with the hosts added before modifications.
But now, when I add news hosts, they aren't persisted. After a while they are overwrite. Even if I restart WSL. 
Should I reset my modifications, write on my Windows host file and make my modifications again?

Comment: It finally doesn't work. The hosts written in `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` disapear after a while.

Comment: @Sinedolo Nothing about WSL (or the `wsl.conf`) file should affect your *Windows* hosts file (`c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`).  That's why I say it's odd and asked you to confirm the exact steps above in my previous comment.  Something in a script or task somewhere (either in Windows or WSL) may be changing it, but it shouldn't (dare I say "can't) be the `/etc/wsl.conf` behavior.  That *only* modifies how `/etc/wsl.conf` is treated *inside* WSL.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network, university network, or VPN that might be changing it?

Comment: I am neither on corporate network, university network or VPN. I have installed Win11 for personal use (local network). I removed what I wrote in `/etc/wsl.conf` and restart WSL for repeating what I made. So...

Comment: (1) Add `127.0.0.1 hello-world.local` in `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. (2) `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf` and add `[network] generateHosts = false` (two lines). (3) `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and remove the three first comments (# This fils was...). Now the first line is `127.0.0.1 localhost`. (4) Exit bash and open PowerShell, then `wsl --shutdown`, `wsl -l -v`  (wait 8 secondes) and `wsl`. (5) `cat /etc/hosts` et `cat /etc/wsl.conf`. It's ok, nothing changed. (6) Repeat the steps 4 and 5. Still ok. A few moment later... The content of `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` disappear.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I got fed up with it so I reinstalled everything (including the OS) for looking when my poblem appears. I realised that the beginning of my problem was due to an update of my antivirus. I have disabled "Scan hosts file" and it's working now.

Comment: @Sinedolo Good to hear you got it resolved.  I didn't think it was due to WSL ;-).  Would you mind adding that as an *answer* rather than an edit to the question?  You can then self-accept the answer (after 24 hours, I believe) so that the question will get closed-out properly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overwriting of the Windows hosts file was due to my antivirus, Bitdefender Total Security. I disabled the *"Scan hosts file"* setting, and it now works.

Comment: Bitdefender Total Security